# PySpark OutOfMemoryErrors when performing many dataframe joins

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

There's many posts about this issue, but none have answered my question.

I'm running into `OutOfMemoryError`s in PySpark while attempting to join many  different dataframes together.

My local machine has 16GB of memory, and I've set my Spark configurations as such:

```
class SparkRawConsumer:

    def __init__(self, filename, reference_date, FILM_DATA):
        self.sparkContext = SparkContext(master='local[*]', appName='my_app')
        SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '3g')
        SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.driver.memory', '15g')
```

There are clearly many, many SO posts about OOM errors in Spark, but basically most of them say to increase your memory  properties.

I am essentially performing joins from 50-60 smaller dataframes, which have two columns `uid`, and `data_in_the_form_of_lists` (usually, it's a list of Python strings). My master dataframe that I am joining on has about 10 columns, but also contains a `uid` column (that I am joining on).

I'm only attempting to join 1,500 rows of data. However, I'll encounter frequent OutOfMemory errors, when clearly all this data can fit into memory. I confirm this by looking in my SparkUI at my Storage:

[image: Spark UI screenshot]

In code, my joins look like this:

```
# lots of computations to read in my dataframe and produce metric1, metric2, metric3, .... metric 50
metrics_df = metrics_df.join(
                self.sqlContext.createDataFrame(metric1, schema=["uid", "metric1"]), on="uid")

metrics_df.count()
metrics_df.repartition("gid_value")
metrics_df = metrics_df.join(
                self.sqlContext.createDataFrame(metric2, schema=["uid", "metric2"]),
                on="gid_value")

metrics_df.repartition("gid_value")
metrics_df = metrics_df.join(
                self.sqlContext.createDataFrame(metric3, schema=["uid", "metric3"]),
                on="uid")

metrics_df.count()
metrics_df.repartition("gid_value")
```

Where `metric1`, `metric2` and `metric3` are RDDs that I convert into dataframes prior to the join (keep in mind there's actually 50 of these smaller `metric` dfs I am joining).

I call `metric.count()` to force evaluation, since it seemed to help prevent the memory errors (I would get many more driver errors when attempting the final collect otherwise).

The errors are non-deterministic. I don't see them occurring at any particular spot in my joins consistently, and sometimes appears to be occurring my final `metrics_df.collect()` call, and sometimes during the smaller joins.

I really suspect there's some issues with task serialization/deserialization. For instance, when I look at my Event Timeline for a typical stage, I see that the bulk of it is taken up by task deserialization:

[image: Spark UI screenshot serialization]

I also notice that there's a huge number for garbage collection time:

[image: Spark UI screenshot garbage collection]

Is garbage collection the issue in causing the memory errors? Or is it task serialization?

#### Edit to answer comment questions

I've been running the Spark job as part of a larger PyCharm project (hence why the spark context was wrapped around a class). I refactored the code to run it as a script, using the following spark submit:

```
spark-submit spark_consumer.py \
  --driver-memory=10G \
  --executor-memory=5G \
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps'
```

Comment: I am not sure about this is the reason but you can't set driver-memory from application. You need to set it before applications start (spark-env or spark-submit).

Comment: Can you share the `spark-submit` command you are using? A high GC time is indicative of memory pressure, even without an OOM error. Notice your "Storage Memory" column says you have `384MB` available, this would point to @hamzatuna being correct about not launching the driver with the correct memory allocation.

Comment: @TravisHegner I have answered your question in my edit above

Comment: When you initilze SpartContext spark submit configurations will be dismissed. You should you SparkContext().getOrCreate() method.

Comment: @hamzatuna I've changed my code to be       
`self.sparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate()`... however, I still see that I have less than 400MB of memory available.

Comment: You set any configuration on code?

Comment: @hamzatuna. No- the code I provided is it. I removed my `SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '3g')` based on your comment.

Comment: You can try without any = operator in spark-submit. Can you try like that --driver-memory 10g

Comment: @hamzatuna unfortunately, my memory available still remains the exact same.

Comment: I added how I solved in my case. It worked maybe you have another reason? You have any executor or cluster.

Comment: It is running now, and I do see that my memory load has increased. We'll see if it is able to run successfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue and it worked with:
Spark Submit:

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 3g\
            --executor-memory 14g\
            *.py
```

Code:

```
sc = SparkContext().getOrCreate()
```