# pyspark.ml - NGrams + CountVectorizer - Sorted based on count weights

Tags: hive, pyspark, heap-memory, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to find the ngram countvectorizer and sort the output based on count weights. 
I have used below approach:

1. **Step A.** Find the ngram countvectorizer in spark layer.
2. **Step B.** Save the pyspark ml dataframe to Hive table.

**Issue Faced:**
 Getting Java Heap Space in Step B.

**Queries:**

A. Before doing step B, rather than writing all below columns in hive
    table; will it be good thought to only few columns say (1_links,
    1_counts); (2_links, 2_counts) and (3_links, 3_counts) in separate
    tables. That way data getting written to hive table will be reduced.
    The pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame is having below cols:
    id,urllinks, 1_links,2_links,3_links,
    1_counts,2_counts,3_counts

B. The columns 1_counts, 2_counts and 3_counts; can these be converted from Sparse Vector to Dense Vector; and take out only those indexes whose count is more than a threshold (say 3). This way data getting written Hive table will be reduced and chances of Java heap space error will be less.

If these approaches are good, please let know how to perform that. I was unable to do that (provided will not get Java Heap Space Error).

C. How to get vocabulary in the same hive table with counts.

D. How to deal with Java Heap space error. Which parameters I need to look into. Have used below settings, while starting the notebook.

```
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS='--master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 24 -- 
executor-memory 50g --driver-memory 200g --default-parallelism 2500 --driver- 
maxResultSize 100g --executor-cores 10 --conf 
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=100g'
```

Please also let know, is there any other approach which can be taken.

Note:
1. Data is very huge (every hour get million of click stream rows) and cant pull data to local disk and do countvectorizer in scikitlearn.

**Have written below code:**

Started Jupyter Notebook Using below settings:

```
`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter" PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --port=XXXX --no-browser --ip= --NotebookApp.token= " PYSPARK_PYTHON="/opt/anaconda/anaconda4/bin/python" PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS='--master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 24 --executor-memory 50g --driver-memory 200g --default-parallelism 2500 --driver-maxResultSize 100g --executor-cores 10 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=100g' PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter" pyspark`
```

**Code is as below:**

```
# Import
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext ,HiveContext ,Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd
from time import time
import math

from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, MapType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, MapType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from collections import Counter

from pyspark.ml.feature import NGram

from pyspark.ml.feature import NGram, CountVectorizer, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector

# Setting Spark Context
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

#Creating the pyspark ml dataframe
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT id, collect_set(urllink) as urllinks FROM clik_stream \
where click_year='2018' and click_month='02' and click_day='02' GROUP BY id")

def build_ngrams_part(inputCol="urllinks", n=3):

   ngrams = [
      NGram(n=i, inputCol="urllinks", outputCol="{0}_links".format(i))
      for i in range(1, n + 1)
   ]

   vectorizers = [
    CountVectorizer(inputCol="{0}_links".format(i),
        outputCol="{0}_counts".format(i))
    for i in range(1, n + 1)
   ]


#     assembler = [VectorAssembler(
#         inputCols=["{0}_counts".format(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)],
#         outputCol="features"
#     )]

#    return Pipeline(stages=ngrams + 
DenseVector(SparseVector(vectorizers).toArray()))
   return Pipeline(stages=ngrams + vectorizers)

a = build_ngrams_part().fit(df)
b = a.transform(df)

b.write.saveAsTable("output")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a6183cfa83e6> in <module>()
----> 1 b.write.saveAsTable("output")

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in saveAsTable(self, name, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    631         if format is not None:
    632             self.format(format)
--> 633         self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
    634 
    635     @since(1.4)

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o191.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeAndRead(DataSource.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.saveDataIntoTable(createDataSourceTables.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:420)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ByteBufferOutputStream.write(ByteBufferOutputStream.scala:41)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2289)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:841)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)

​
```

I ran the code on sample data set(to check the logic). It is working as desired.

```
df_test = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, ["a", "b", "c", "d"]),
  (2, ["d", "e", "d"]),
  (3, ["e", "f", "e"]),    
], ("id", "urllinks"))

a = build_ngrams_part().fit(df_test)
b = a.transform(df_test)
b.show(3)

stages = a.stages
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizerModel

vectorizers = [s for s in stages if isinstance(s, CountVectorizerModel)]
[v.vocabulary for v in vectorizers]

    +---+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| id|    urllinks|     1_links|        2_links|       3_links|            1_counts|            2_counts|           3_counts|
+---+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|  1|[a, b, c, d]|[a, b, c, d]|[a b, b c, c d]|[a b c, b c d]|(6,[1,2,3,4],[1.0...|(7,[0,2,3],[1.0,1...|(4,[0,2],[1.0,1.0])|
|  2|   [d, e, d]|   [d, e, d]|     [d e, e d]|       [d e d]| (6,[0,1],[1.0,2.0])| (7,[1,4],[1.0,1.0])|      (4,[3],[1.0])|
|  3|   [e, f, e]|   [e, f, e]|     [e f, f e]|       [e f e]| (6,[0,5],[2.0,1.0])| (7,[5,6],[1.0,1.0])|      (4,[1],[1.0])|
+---+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+

b.write.saveAsTable("sample.output")
```

**Please help out with the points in Queries section.**

Comment: You checked driver memory from spark web UI? Sometimes it cannot be setted refer this questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310952/pyspark-outofmemoryerrors-when-performing-many-dataframe-joins/51313008#51313008

Comment: Have used below command, error is same. Is it something to do with saveAsTable 
 `spark-submit *.py --driver-memory=200g --executor-memory=50g --default-parallelism 2500 --driver-maxResultSize 100g --executor-cores 10 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=100g --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps' `

Comment: Spark Submit configurations is dismissed if you initilize sc in code. That can be your problem but i am not sure. Can you try  with sc = SparkContext().getOrCreate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reduced the amount of data going to Hive tables. The error got corrected ..